# Pass parameters to external list on SP2019 Standard

Tags: sharepoint-server, filter, bcs, external-content-type, external-list

I have an external list that is displaying data from a SQL Server view. Now, I want to add filtering. The problem is that I'm working on Standard version of Sharepoint, so no Enterprise webparts are available. It would be fine to get them from query string - unfortunately no Url Query String webpart. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a query string, here is the documentation:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/bcs-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint#constructing-query-strings-for-filtering-data

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be building another list with same column values, and then configure a **web part connection** to the External list, acting as filters.

Reference: [Connect web parts in SharePoint.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec)